# How do I pause a screen scraping process every n iterations?

Tags: python, multithreading

python devs. I have a conceptual question. I'm writing some screen scraping code that retrieves data from the same website, but with 5,000 hits to the server with a slightly different connection string each time. I've written it as multithreaded, and its my first use of threading in python.

As it is now, it creates 100 threads and runs, but the program never returns (I did join the threads at the end of the module). When I run just 1,000 queries, it does run as expected and all is well (it returns). Over 1,000, I see max retry errors in the console. So my question is...

How do I pause every 1,000 runs at the server for one minute before continuing, in a multithreaded context?

I'm not sure if I should use an incremented counter in the module, and if I do, do I need to synchronize access to it with a lock? Is this something that can be done best utilizing the queue? I've been searching for relevant info on this application off and on all week, and the best conceptual approach eludes me. Any ideas? Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Keep a nbThreads variable that you increase at each created thread, and decrease at the end of every thread process.

```
while ...
  #Create 1000 threads
  while nbThreads >0:
    time.sleep(2)
  time.sleep(60)
```

You can add a timeout in the thread class to make sure all threads are done after a certain amount of time or to intercept the timeout and actually decrease nbThreads

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't entirely get it, though, as you've described. At the moment I use 1000 threads, but run 5000 web queries (I think this is what you mean by thread process). That being the case, how can one variable accurately account for the thread creation as well as server queries?